# Intercom Interface return text with symbol "_"

Tags: swift, swift5, intercom, intercom-ios

I have checked and implemented the intercom SDK in my ios app as per instructions given in intercom guideline document and Its working fine but I'm facing an issue that the some of the strings in the interface show with _. Like your_conversation, send_us_a_message instead of simple string. I have searched about it but didn't found any solution yet.For more reference please check the below screenshot :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cCT2.png)

Comment: What is the language on your simulator? And what is your "Default language" value in intercom admin panel -> messenger customization?

Comment: Hi @MikhailVasilev, Thanks for reply. My simulator's default language is English, and I don't have any idea about intercom admin panel's language as I'm using key and id shared by one of my client. Can you please let me know more about messenger customisation so that I can resolve above problem as I don't have any idea about it.

Comment: Hi @user14588583! I've posted my thoughts as an answer, because of comment limits:)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't met this confusing strings, but i suppose the problem is in the intercom admin panel config, so you should ask your customer what settings he has. I think there can be two reasons:

**1.** Default language in messenger (*admin panel -> messenger -> Set your welcome message -> Default language*).  May be there is a probability that it’s not english (for example Finnish) and Intercom doesn’t have proper localized strings for this language. 
[image: Default language]

**2.** You client use kinda "override intercom’s default texts" feature like [this](https://lokalise.com/product/integrations/content-management/intercom-articles).  So may be he has this kind of integration but some of the string values are missing. You can ask checking what kind of integrations he has here   :
[image: Integrations]

---

- Also you can try using your intercom client from web
  interface if possible, does it has the same missing texts?
- It's always good thing to check if intercom sdk has the same wrong behaviour in the new "fresh created" xcode project - to clarify that the problem is not inside your project
- And the last thing is you can write to intercom support, it’s pretty fast and responsive.

Comment: okay I'll check it. Thanks for your help.